# Graphing Dynamic Line Graphs for ComboGraph Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

I want to create a combo chart with 2 line graphs. One of them is sourced from a pivot table in another worksheet and another is a horizontal line which may be
adjusted.(Think of equation y = 500.) How can I graph the second graph?

The circled number is horizontal graph (y = 18879.00) and it can change. How can 
I graph the dynamic horizontal graph?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using a pivot chart, you can create a Calculated Field with the value of the line, add that to the chart and format the series as a line. With this technique, the line will not be dynamic and you will need to change the calculated field value when you want to move the line.

[image]

If you want the line to be dynamically linked to data in a cell, then you can't use a pivot chart. You'll need to create a regular chart from the pivot table data and add the line as a new data series. There are several techniques how to achieve that. The screenshot shows how the line can be plotted by having one value for the first and the last data point each. Cells H3 and H14 both point to H18, where the line value can be changed in one cell.

Add the data in H3:H14 as a new series and format as a line. If the line does not show, make sure to set the option for "Hidden and empty cells" to **connect data points with line**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just for reference, to create a combo chart that sources its data from a pivot table: 1) Select and insert blank chart. 2) Right-click and select "Source from Data" 3) No need to add to data range. 4) Add the data series. Select the series and enter in a name.